# Conditions for monotonic convergence in the CLT?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, reference-request, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

(Revised to assume $\text{support}(X_i)=\mathbb{N}$ in response to counterexamples noted in comments.)

Let $S_n=X_1+...+X_n$, where the $X_i$ are i.i.d. with $\text{support}(X_i)=\mathbb{N}$ and $0<VX_i<\infty.$ Then we know by the CLT that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}P({S_n<ES_n})={1\over 2}.$$

**Q1**: What are necessary and/or sufficient conditions for the convergence of $P({S_n<ES_n})$ to be **monotonic**?

For the $X_i$-distributions that I've examined numerically (e.g., Negative Binomial and Poisson), computations suggest that $EX_i\in\mathbb{N}$ is neccesary & sufficient -- but I've been unable to prove it.

For example, if $X_i\sim\text{Geometric($p$)}$, then $EX_i\in\mathbb{N}$ iff $1/p\in\mathbb{N}$, and indeed the convergence appears monotonic iff $p$ is the reciprocal of a positive integer.

Similarly, if $X_i\sim\text{Poisson($\lambda$)}$, then $EX_i\in\mathbb{N}$ iff $\lambda\in\mathbb{N},$ and indeed the convergence appears monotonic iff $\lambda$ is a positive integer.

Here are some typical plots of $P({S_n<ES_n})$ v. $n$:

$X_i\sim\text{Geometric($p=1/3$)},\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \text{Geometric($p=1/3.1$)}$
[image]

$X_i\sim\text{Poisson($\lambda=1$)},\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \text{Poisson($\lambda=1.1$)}$
[image]

Here's my attempt to prove (strict) monotonicity when $X_i\sim\text{Geometric($p=1/3$)}$; i.e., $S_n\sim\text{NegativeBinomial($n,p=1/3$)},$ for which $ES_n=nq/p=2n$, with $q=1-p.$ The pmf of $S_n$ is the following:
$$P(S_n=k) = \binom{k+n-1}{n-1} p^nq^k\quad(k=0,1,2,...),$$
and we want to show that for all $n$,
$$\begin{align}P(S_{n+1}<ES_{n+1}) &< P(S_{n}<ES_{n}) \\[2ex]
\sum_{k=0}^{2(n+1)-1}\binom{k+n}{k}p^{n+1}q^k &< \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\binom{k+n-1}{k}p^{n}q^k\\[2ex]
\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}\binom{k+n}{k}q^k &< \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\binom{k+n}{k}{3n\over k+n}q^k\\[2ex]
\sum_{k=2n}^{2n+1}\binom{k+n}{k}q^k &< \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\binom{k+n}{k}\left({3n\over k+n}-1\right)q^k\\[2ex]
\binom{3n}{2n}q^{2n}+ \binom{3n+1}{2n+1}q^{2n+1}&< \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\binom{k+n}{k}\left({3n\over k+n}-1\right)q^k\\[2ex]
{12n+5\over 12n+3}\binom{3n}{2n}\left({2\over 3}\right)^{2n}&< \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{k+n}{k}\left({2n-k\over k+n}\right)\left({2\over 3}\right)^k\tag{*}\\[2ex]
...\ & ?\ ...
\end{align}$$

**Q2**: Any suggestions on how to proceed, or alternative approaches? (I tried using the cdf in the form of a regularized beta function, but it led to similar difficulty.) Anyone know of binomial identities/inequalities that will further simplify (*)?

Comment: It seems highly unlikely to me that $EX_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ is the relevant condition, since that's not invariant under scaling — if $EX_i\in\mathbb{Q}$ then you can always scale to make it $\in\mathbb{Z}$, and contrariwise if it always held for $EX_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ then you could e.g. take the $X_i$ to be in $2\mathbb{Z}$ with $EX_i\in\mathbb{Z}$, scale by 1/2, and get a case with all $X_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ but $EX_i$ not necessarily so.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Yes, perhaps the condition should rather be $ES_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n$?

Comment: That would have the same vulnerability to scaling, I believe.

Comment: Maybe the assumption should be that the $X$s are supported on an AP, and that $\mathbb{E}[X]$ should be divisible by the common difference of that AP? This is at least invariant to scaling. For divisibility there could be a catch due to translation, which perhaps can be handled by enforcing that $0$ is in the support.

Comment: Also, an obervation in favour of some integrality type property of $\mathbb{E}[X]$ being the condition is that in the plots if we move $n$ in steps of size $k$ so that $k\mathbb{E}[X]$ is an integer, then we again see monotone behaviour - every 3rd point in the first Bernoulli case seems to do this, and so does every 10th point in the geometric and poisson cases (I can't really eyeball 31 points, but if the repeating structure is of that length then I guess this is also true for the second Bernoulli plot).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki & stochasticboy321 Another counterexample is when $X_i$ has a symmetric distribution on three consecutive integers, say on $\{k-1,k,k+1\}$ with corresponding probabilities $\{{1-p\over 2}, p, {1-p\over 2}\}.$ Then, although $EX_i=k\in\mathbb{Z},$ it's easily shown that $P(S_n<ES_n)$ is non-monotonic if $p<{1\over 3}.$

Comment: I've revised the main question to assume $\text{support}(X_i)=\mathbb{N},$ which should prevent the counterexamples so far noted.  (I'm most interested in determining whether $EX_i\in\mathbb{N}$ is sufficient for monotonicity when the $X_i$-distribution is Geometric.)